# free() on struct member causes Hardfault only in Debug

Tags: c, arm, gdb, stm32, memory-alignment

I am working on a STM32F7.
A Hardfault is triggered when I hit the `free()` in the following (simplified) code:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t* data;
}my_struct;

void foo()
{
     my_struct msg;
     msg.size = 5;
     msg.data = malloc(msg.size);
     if(msg.data != NULL)
     {
         free(msg.data); // Hardfault
     }
}
```

Going step by step with GDB in the `free()` I found the assembly instruction that caused the Hardfault:

```
ldrd    r1, r3, [r5, #8]
```

The value of `r5` is `0x5F0FE9D0`

`CFSR` is `0x8200` and both `MMFAR` and `BFAR` registers contains `0x5F0FE9D8`,

Looking at **LDRDR** problems on the net, I tried to add `__attribute__((__packed__))` to `my_struct` definition.
It is supposed to force the compiler to generate 2x**LDR** instead when using unaligned memory access via pointers/structures.

By doing that, I no longer have an Hardfault at runtime. OK...

Out of curiosity, I wanted to inspect the addresses via GDB after this modification, and surprise ! Nothing changes (I mean about the addresses) and I ends up hitting the **LDRD** instruction again, despite the `packed`, and generating my Hardfault (but only in GDB-debug execution).

I launched a new run after removing the attribute and compared the value of `MMFAR` and `BFAR` registers and when I am not in GDB I got `0x41AFFE60`

- Why can't I see the 2x**LDR** in the debugger ?
- More generally, why don't I have the same behavior with and without GDB ?
- Is the `packed` trick is the good solution for my issue ?

P.S. I am running FreeRTOS and have defined `configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW` to 2 and `configASSERT`, nothing triggers.

Comment: As pointed out by others, you might be experiencing some memory corruption. This might be a stack overflow into the heap or other static vars, depending on your memory layout. But it's just guessing. I'd suggest you double check your memory map.
Regarding the (packed) attribute, I'm not sure how that would help. If anything, it would make things worse IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `0x5F0FE9D8` and `0x41AFFE60` are marked as reserved in the STM32F7 memory map (chapter 2 of the Reference Manual). It means that **the heap is corrupted**.

> Why can't I see the 2xLDR in the debugger ?

Because `free()` is in a precompiled static library, it's not recompiled.

> More generally, why don't I have the same behavior with and without GDB ?

If the heap contains random junk, either because it's not initialized properly, or overwritten by some unrelated piece of code, you might get some different junk when you connect things to, or disconnect things from the board. Or whenever some environmental factor changes.

> Is the `packed` trick is the good solution for my issue ?

No, it just manages to hide the problem by sheer luck. With a corrupt heap, all bets are off.

Answer (score -1):

You are starting debugging from the wrong end. Did you check the value returned by malloc? Probably not.

If the address is invalid it usually means that your linker script is wrong.

Show  us everything. The result of the malloc, the actual code and the linker script.

Comment: I checked the address returned by malloc and it is in the valid range of my defined heap in linker script. Unfortunately I cannot share the actual code as I'm working on proprietary project...

Comment: If you do not show the real code, there is no help possible. Do you think that anyone is interested in the uC code using mallocs?

Comment: I am not saying that it is important or whatever, I just comply to the NDA. Also I do not expect SO to debug my code, I just needed pointers and your gave some :)